# I have a question about URI templates in WCF Services

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a web service with following operation contract and my service is hosted at `http://localhost:9002/Service.svc/`

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Files/{Filepath}")]
Stream DownloadFile(string Filepath);
```

This web service would let users download file, if the proper `filepath` is provided (assuming, I somehow find out that proper filepath).

Now, I can access this service from a browser by typing, `http://localhost:9002/Service.svc/Files/(Filepath}`

If `{filepath}` is some simple string, its not a problem, but I want to send the location of the file. Lets us say users want to download file `C:\Test.mp3` on the server. But how can I pass `C:\Test.mp3` as `{Filepath}`? I get an error when I type `http://localhost:9002/Service.svc/Files/C:\Test.mp3` in the browser.

I am new to web services and find that this community is the quickest way to get answers to my questions.

got it working now.
need to use HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode() from System.web

Comment: Reference System.Web, and then call `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` on your file path - that turns the : and \ into URL codes which should be fine on the URL

Comment: It still doesnt work, it encode ':' and '\' but does not encode '.'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot type special characters like ":" and "\" as part of a URL. They will need to be URL encoded.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to URL encode the string, then decode on the back end.  Add System.Web to your project and use [System.Web.HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx).UrlEncode() then System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode()